# Why do I have more rep from this year than my total reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I was looking at my profile, and *"Oooh! Top 2% this year? Lets take a look!"*

[image: Rep league pic 1]

**Wait, how the hell is my total reputation less than my reputation this year?**

After some investigation, it seems that this happens to most users who have not previously been ranked (i.e. have joined the site this year). Here are some other examples:

[image: Rep league pic 2]

[image: Rep league pic 3]

Comment: cant tell you everything that goes into it, but you can receive negative reputation for things such as down-voting, and being down-voted.

Comment: @Timelord64 I know, but wouldn't the year reputation be net rep, not positive rep only?

Comment: I imagine so. But likewise, the total rep would also reflect net rep, and could be lower if it is accounting for negative rep in the previous year.

Comment: @Timelord64 But I haven't had my arqade account before this year, so that can't be the case.